# jquery simulate "fake" form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am building a template for a project and it currently has no server side built. I need to test my forms and validations and want to "fake" a form submission.

I am trying this:

```
$("#save").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest("form").find("input").prop('disabled',true);
  $("#save").prop('disabled',true);
  $("#edit").prop('disabled',false);
  //submit form via ajax to be built
  $("form").submit(function() {
    alert('success');
  });
});
```

this is not working as I thought it may.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Try passing a callback function to submit.  You should be able to console.log something to see if it "worked".

Comment: I updated to my current code and still not working

Comment: Include HTML, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`submit` method takes in an event parameter which has the `preventDefault` method. So your code should look something like the example below:

```js
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('print something here!');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <input label="Name" type="text" />
  <input label="Password" type="text" />
  <input label="submit" type="submit" />
</form>
```

For more info, you can always check the official [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/submit/).

Comment: still not working, could it be that i am using <button type="submit"> instead of <input type="submit"> ???

Comment: Make sure that all the input are wrapped inside a form. Then, I believe it should work. Check my updated answer.